# Getting the correct name of clicked input from a list JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm struggling to use jquery to identify the button i'm clicking.

I've a dynamically generated list categories along with a Remove button to delete it from the database.

My inputs are like this:

```
<input id="deletesector" class="deletesector" type="submit" name="deletesector-4" value="Remove"></input>
<input id="deletesector" class="deletesector" type="submit" name="deletesector-5" value="Remove"></input>
<input id="deletesector" class="deletesector" type="submit" name="deletesector-6" value="Remove"></input>
```

my script listens for a .deletesector click and then get the attr name. however, it returns the name of deletesector-4 no matter which of the 3 buttons is clicked.

How do I fix this so that if "deletesector-5" is clicked it identifies it as such.

```
  $(".deletesector").click(function() {  

    //store the id
    var name = $("input#deletesector").attr('name'); 

    //create the post variable string
    var dataString = 'serviceid='+ name;  
    alert (dataString);
```

Comment: [An `id` ***must be unique within the document***](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) otherwise the HTML is invalid. And that makes JavaScript break, and puppies cry.

Comment: Is 'name' a PROPERTY or an ATTRIBUTE ?

Comment: @MilchePatern I guess that depends on what version of jQuery he's using....

Answer (score 5):

Use `this` inside the anonymous function for the click-handler:

```
$(".deletesector").click(function(){  
    var name = this.name
});
```

The reason you always got the `name` of `deleteselector4` is because that's the first (but not the only) element with the `id` of `deleteselector`, an `id` must be unique for HTML to be valid. With that in mind `id` selectors only ever look for *one* element when they search by `id`, and stop at that *first* element, assuming it's the only element with that `id` (as it should be).

Given that the `id` in your HTML is the same as the `class`, remove the `id` since it's doing nothing useful, and actively harming your HTML's validity.

References:

- [Element identifiers: the `id` and `class` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$(".deletesector").click(function(){  
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    // your stuff here
});
```

`this` in a jQuery event refers to the element that was clicked on.

Also, your duplicate `id`s will mess stuff up.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/LupZw/) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have some duplicated ids.
Here is the fixed code:

```
<input id="deletesector-4" class="deletesector" type="submit" name="deletesector-4" value="Remove"></input>
<input id="deletesector-5" class="deletesector" type="submit" name="deletesector-5" value="Remove"></input>
<input id="deletesector-6" class="deletesector" type="submit" name="deletesector-6" value="Remove"></input>
```

Then you **jQuery** could be like this:

```
$(".deletesector").click(function(ev) {
  // CHECK THIS $(ev.target) element, very useful!
  elementClicked = $(ev.target);
  var name = elementClicked.attr('name'); 
  var dataString = 'serviceid='+ name;
  alert (dataString);
});
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leonardorb/yjwLM/) that shows your example working.